# Mongo FindOne return results in error parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing a login system in NodeJS with a Mongo database, so I try to look in my collection if the user exist. For my tests, I have a user registered, and I'm trying to find him.

My problem is that findOne method return the full user' data as I wish, but in the error parameter, not in the results parameter, and I have no logs to understand why...

Did somebody know why ?

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body.identifier);
    console.log(req.body.password);

    client.connect().then(() => {

        let newUser = {identifier : req.body.identifier}
        res.redirect(req.body.locator)
      
        return client.db(`${process.env.MONGODB}`).collection(`${process.env.MONGOCOLLECTION}`).findOne(newUser).then((err, res) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("ERROR: "+err.role)
                throw err;

            }else if(res){
                console.log("user found");
                console.log(res.role)
            }
      })
    }).catch( e => { console.error(e) }).then(() => {
        console.log("--------------------------------");
    })
})
```

And this is what I got :

```
mail@mail.com
azer
ERROR: USER
{
  _id: 6087d850ad9f6f2e0ce97045,
  identifier: 'mail@mail.com',
  password: '7657d9148a5720dcf4eb4b8bc998498e5d701ce7beb302f398c3d5c0dbd0f857f824b7bfaa45c2a8aba4f85c4ab8b12c99bfb28328e72a89afe11326dc1d3a38349c1c36790a24c910528ada34529e6736ae45f0e5d87ce6b109207e21169bc9b4056fff',
  role: 'USER',
  sign_up: 2021-04-27T09:24:32.616Z,
  name: 'Test',
  firstName: 'Test'
}
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because your code mixes Promises and callbacks. In particular:

```js
findOne(newUser).then((err, res) => {
  // (this does not work because .then() takes a function with 1 argument)
})
```

Promises have a built-in error handling mechanism where a resolver can either *resolve* or *reject* the promise, triggering the `.then()` (success) or the `.catch()` (failure) branch.

See the note at the top of the relevant [manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/findOne/). Also, MongoDB provides [a short guide on Promises vs. callbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/promises/) - pay attention especially to this snippet:

```js
collection
  .updateOne({ name: "Mount McKinley" }, { $set: { meters: 6190 } })
  .then(
    res => console.log(`Updated ${res.result.n} documents`),
    err => console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`),
  );
```

Note how `.then()` accepts **two functions** above - these are separate callbacks for the "success" case and the "error" case.

Answer (score 1):

Read - [Promises and Callbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/promises/)

Here you're using promise - `then` will give the result and `catch` will give the error.

```
client.db(`${process.env.MONGODB}`)
    .collection(`${process.env.MONGOCOLLECTION}`)
    .findOne(newUser)
    .then( res => { ... }) // result 
    .catch(err => { ... }) // error
```

---

Callback style

```
client.db(`${process.env.MONGODB}`)
    .collection(`${process.env.MONGOCOLLECTION}`)
    .findOne(newUser, (err, res) => { ...  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb was returning the data, and the data was taken as first argument in the then block named as err, try changing to this:

```
  app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.identifier);
  console.log(req.body.password);

  client
    .connect()
    .then(() => {
      let newUser = { identifier: req.body.identifier };
      res.redirect(req.body.locator);

      return client
        .db(`${process.env.MONGODB}`)
        .collection(`${process.env.MONGOCOLLECTION}`)
        .findOne(newUser, (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.role);
            throw err;
          } else if (res) {
            console.log("user found");
            console.log(res.role);
          }
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("--------------------------------");
    });
});
```